# Loop through programmatically added html in literal control

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I was wondering if there is a way to loop through the HTML checkboxes that I have added in a `literal` from codebehind.

I have tried:

```
Protected Sub SplitPDFPagesButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SplitPDFPagesButton.Click
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    For Each c As Control In Page.Controls
        If TypeOf c Is HtmlInputCheckBox Then
            Dim cb As HtmlInputCheckBox = DirectCast(c, HtmlInputCheckBox)
            If cb.Checked = True Then
                i += 1
            End If
        End If
    Next
    MsgBox(i)
End Sub
```

but I think my problem is that the loop finds only the literal as the container(?).

The reason for doing this is because I don't actually know how many checkboxes will be generated before runtime.

This is my code so far (as you will notice from the commented out section, I have tried adding ASP.NET controls and replacing `HtmlInputCheckbox` from the snippet above with `Checkbox`):

```
For Each fil As FileInfo In AllFiles
    '##########################################################
    'Add Image Controls
    'Dim hl As New HyperLink
    'hl.ID = pageCount
    'hl.CssClass = "preview"
    'hl.NavigateUrl = "xxx"
    'hl.ImageUrl = "xxx"
    'hl.Width = 20%
    'hl.Height = 20%
    'form1.Controls.Add(hl)
    'form1.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<br />"))
    ''Add Checkboxes
    'Dim chb As New CheckBox
    'chb.ID = pageCount
    'chb.Text = "Break Here"

    'Dim lb As New Label
    'lb.Text = "Page #" & pageCount
    'form1.Controls.Add(lb)
    'form1.Controls.Add(chb)
    'form1.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<br />"))
    'pageCount += 1
    '############################################################

    With str
        '.AppendLine("<img src=""xxx"" style=""width:50%; height:50%""/><br />")
        .AppendLine("<b>Page #: " & pageCount & "</b>")
        .AppendLine("<div class=""leavespace""></div>")
        .AppendLine("<a href=""xxx"" & """ class=""preview""><img src=""xxx & """ style=""width:20%; height:20%;""/></a><br />")
        '.AppendLine(Environment.NewLine)
        .AppendLine("-------------------<br />")
        .AppendLine("<input type=""checkbox"" value=" & pageCount & ">Break Here</input><br />")
        .AppendLine("-------------------<br />")
        .AppendLine("<div class=""leavespace""></div>")
        '.AppendLine(Environment.NewLine)
    End With
    pageCount += 1
Next

str.AppendLine("</div>")
Literal1.Text = str.ToString
```

Answer (score 0):

In general the only way to to get at regular HTML elements from the code behind is to add the attribute runat="server", but I do not believe that this is possible within an asp.net literal control, as literal is used to represent static elements and text on the page.  I may not be correct though.

Take a look at this:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.literalcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.literalcontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)